# Looping over Firestore to get document ids

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm trying to get all the user's id present and store in an array list.

Here's my collection

[image]

here's my code:

```
` firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query firstQuery=firebaseFirestore.collection("Users");
firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            lastVisible=documentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                    .get(documentSnapshots.size() -1);
        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                String blogPostId=doc.getDocument().getId();

                ArrayList.add(doc.getDocument());         }


    }
});`
```

I am fairly new to firebase.
Thank you

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @HemantParmar I have updated it

Comment: document id is store in your random collection ? for ex : User --> random collection -- > document_id ?

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code? Do you have an error? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the structure of your User Model, add a user_id field in your User model and match it so that it will be equal to the Uid generated by Firebase.Then make sure that when a User is created your document id will be equal to your user id
you can then retrieve it and store it in an ArrayList. I'll write the logic the rest should be easy for you to implement.

```
                        //implementing user model in registration



                        //getting the database reference
                        FirebaseFirestore mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                        Users user = new User();
                        user.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                                .build();
                        mDb.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
                        // we make sure that the document id is equal to user id
                        DocumentReference newUserRef = mDb
                                .collection("Users")
                                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

                        newUserRef.set(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                              }
                       });
```

Then in your activity :

```
    ArrayList<Users> listUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    //getting the database reference
    FirebaseFirestore mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    CollectionReference reference =  mDb.collection(Users);
    //Retrieving the data from the database
    reference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                //We specify that we want the id and add it to the arrayList
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    Users users = document.toObject(Users.class);
                    listUSers.add(user.getId());


                }
```